# date validation not to be today

Tags: php, date

I need to validate 2 date that never should be same.If same it will return false.Code is in PHP.It is always giving o/p as false.

```
function BeforeAdd($values, $message, $inline, $pageObject)
{
$d1 =$values['DATE'];     //date 1 in dd/mm/yyyy format
$d2 =$values['DATE OF LEAVE'];   //date 2 in dd/mm/yyyy format
if($d1 <> $d2)
{
return true;  
}
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert(Application date and leave date should be different.)';
echo '</script>';
return false;  
}
```

I have another code that is working partially.

```
function BeforeAdd($values, $message, $inline, $pageObject)
{
$d1 =$values['DATE'];     //date 1 in dd/mm/yyyy format
$d2 =now();  
if($d1>$d2)
{
return true;  
}
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert(Application date and leave date should be different.)';
echo '</script>';
return false;  
}
```

When i am using this if($d1<>$d2) it is allowing everything.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Above code is for php.

Comment: Mr.Milz  Prob is it is always giving o/p as false.

Comment: It doesn't always return false - [Demo](http://ideone.com/b8Lima) - are you certain that the $values array contains what you think?

Comment: Infact it is a code that to be executed after the form is initiated and before data is saved.It has to check whether the date is today or not .But in this case it is always returning false.Please help

Comment: Should i use date and time for the "date" and "date of leave" fields instead of date only?

Comment: What do you see when you: _`var_dump($d1, $d2, $d1 <> $d2)`_? Are they what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
function BeforeAdd($values, $message='', $inline='', $pageObject='') {

    $d1 =$values['DATE'];     //date 1 in dd/mm/yyyy format
    $d2 =$values['DATE_OF_LEAVE'];   //date 2 in dd/mm/yyyy format

    if($d1 <> $d2) {
        return true;  
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Application date and leave date should be different.")';
    echo '</script>';

    return false; 


}
```

You need to change `$values['DATE OF LEAVE']` to `$values['DATE_OF_LEAVE']`.
Also in the example you have some fields you don't use - I made them optional and changed the javascript code a little.

Comment: Same prob is there its not at all functioning.Returns false without the echo value given.

Comment: Can't you do something like this? http://pixbg.com/images/c989f9ad6aab3db77a87.png You cannot get the string printed by `echo` as the function returns `boolean`.

Comment: Using it in phprunner application.In before add segment put the code.

Comment: Hello Mr.Mario   i tested te code you suggested but it is stopping even if i put two different dates.

Answer (score 0):

U can use fucntion strtotime and compare it

```
 $d1 = "1/2/2015";
 $d2= "1/2/2016";

    if ( strtotime($d1) == strtotime($d2) )
       echo "same";
     else
       echo "different";
```

copy this code and test it i resolve your problem this is my last edit

```
<?php
$d1 = "1/2/2015";
$d2= "1/2/2015";





    if ( strtotime($d1) != strtotime($d2) ) {
        return true;  
    }
    else
    {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Application date and leave date should be different.")';
    echo '</script>';

    return false;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Its now returning false with an echo everytime i put even different dates

Comment: if ( strtotime($d1) == strtotime($d2) ) change statment i test it on my localhost and it works

Comment: it is allowing both equal dates and unequal dates

Comment: this code work if u send 2 different dates it return true, if date is same u will get false. That is what u ask in question and i resolve that

Comment: i put 2 different dates it returned true also true for same date

Comment: i hope u dont joking with me, gl i resolve your problem ths is not chat

Comment: Why should i buddy? it is returning false for all cases when i use !== and returning true for all cases when i put == Should i format the date?

Comment: $d1 =$values['DATE'];     //date 1 in dd/mm/yyyy format
    $d2 =$values['DATE_OF_LEAVE'];   //date 2 in dd/mm/yyyy format

    if(strtotime($d1) !== strtotime($d2)) 
{
        return true;  
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Application date and leave date should be different.")';
    echo '</script>';

    return false;

Comment: u said u have format dd/mm/yyyy and i make d1 and d2 in same format and it work perfect, just copy my code i dont know what u grab with $values['DATE'] if u use same format like u said it must work, just copy my code and test

Answer (score 0):

Any one can suggest me a code to return false id date is today else true in the format

```
function BeforeAdd($values, $message, $inline, $pageObject)
{
    $d1 = $values['DATE'];     //date 1 in dd/mm/yyyy format
    $d2 = now();  

    if($d1>$d2)
    {
        return true;  
    }

    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert(Application date and leave date should be different.)';
    echo '</script>';

    return false;  
}
```